# Laravel whereHas manyToMany exact match

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, query-builder

I have a `Model` with `manyToMany` relationship:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'product_category', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

So 1 `Product` can have multiple `Categories`.

I'm trying to query (fetch) all `Products` that have exact match of categories:

Example:

```php
$categories = ['category1', 'category2'];

Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categories){

    foreach ($categories as $categoryName) {
       $q->where('name', $categoryName);
    }
    //or $q->whereIn('name', $categories);

})->get();
```

Also tried:

```php
$categories = ['category1', 'category2'];

Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categories){

    $q->whereIn('name', $categories);

}, '=', count($categories))->get();
```

Assume my `Product` has only `category1` attached, the query should return this product.

If `Product` has both `categories`, but my array contains only `category1`, then this `Product` should be ignored.

So I'm trying to achieve: Fetch only `products` with specific categories. It is doable with `Eloquent` or `DB` builder?

Pseudo Code

```php
$allow = for each Product->categories{
    category Exist in $categories
}
```

Comment: Why not `whereIn("name", $categories);`? There's no need for a loop.

Comment: @TimLewis, this is the problem, `whereIn` returns all products if it finds at least 1 match, I need exact match, if my array contains `category1`, I don't want to fetch products that contains `category1, category2`, only products that has `category1`, without any other category

Comment: That's not even doable in SQL, at least not directly... if you want to exclude results you can use NOT IN, but you need to know the excluded values in advance

Comment: Hmm, I think I follow. Off the top of my head, a count of the length of `$categories` cross-referenced with the `categories` returned using a `whereIn()` _should_ work, but I'm not sure how you'd code that.

Comment: @TimLewis, in laravel you can pass a `third` argument to compare the count,
Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers I solved this with: [`whereExists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-exists-clauses) of sub select [`fromSub`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-exists-clauses) and [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html), operator [`<@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html) (is contained by):

```php
$categories = ['category1', 'category2'];

Product::whereExists(function ($q) use ($categories){

    $q->fromSub(function ($query) {

        $query->selectRaw("array_agg(categories.name) as categoriesArr")
          ->from('categories')
          ->join('product_category', 'categories.id', '=', 'product_category.category_id')
          ->whereRaw('products.id = product_category.product_id');

    }, 'foo')->whereRaw("categoriesArr <@ string_to_array(?, ',')::varchar[]", [
        implode(",", $categories)
    ]); 

})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement your MySQL query would be as follow:

- Use `LEFT JOIN` to get total numbers of mapped `categories` for a product.
- Use `GROUP BY` on a product to compare its `total mapped categories` vs `matching categories based on user input`.
- Above comparison can be done using `HAVING` clause, where `total mapped categories` should be equal to the count of categories the user has provided. Same `matching categories based on user input` should also match the exact count of categories which the user has provided.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON p.id = pc.product_id 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = pc.category_id AND c.name IN ('category1', 'category2')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(0) = 2   -- To match that product should have only two categories
    AND SUM(IF(c.name IN ('category1', 'category2'), 1, 0)) = 2; -- To match that product have only those two categories which user has provided.
```

Same can be achieved by query builder in the following manner:

```
$arrCategory    =   ['category1', 'category2'];
$strCategory    =   "'" . implode("','", $arrCategory) . "'";
$intLength      =   count($arrCategory);

$products       =   Product::leftJOin('product_category', 'products.id', '=', 'product_category.product_id')
                        ->leftJoin('categories', function ($join) use ($arrCategory) {
                            $join->on('categories.id', '=', 'product_category.category_id')
                                ->whereIn('categories.name', $arrCategory);
                        })
                        ->groupBy('products.id')
                        ->havingRaw("COUNT(0) = $intLength AND SUM(IF(categories.name IN ($strCategory), 1, 0)) = $intLength")
                        ->select(['products.id'])
                        ->get();
dd($products);
```

Note: If you have `only_full_group_by` mode enabled in MySQL, then include columns of products table in both `group by` and `select` clause which you want to fetch.

Comment: Thank you for answer: will check, I have updated my question, (Note: I'm using PostgreSQL)

Comment: I am not aware of postgresSQL but try the same logic if you can build query. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this without wherehas

```
Product::with(array('categories' => function($q) use ($categories){
    $query->whereIn('name', $categories);
}))->get();
```